# Foreground Running in instruments

Tags: ios, swift

So i've been working on mu iOS app's (in swift) performance lately and so I went on instruments and started the running the app under leak checks because I have been having trouble with high memory and thought I should check that. No leaks as far as I can see but on the top of the memory graph at the start of my app's life there is a flag that when I click on it says 'Foreground Running'. What does this mean and how do I fix it?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hi i tried the same thing. This will help you know when you app was running in foreground and background.
Try going to home screen and coming back similar flags you will be able to see .

This will help you know how your app behaves when in the background. Let me know if you have any other question.